# C++ Win32 API - CreateFont(): the documentation example is confusing

Tags: winapi, code-documentation

The Win32 API function `CreateFont()` documentation has a confusing [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta#examples):

As you can see below, they made 3 calls to `CreateFont()` **using the same** `HANDLE` (hFont).. and at the end they have called `DeleteObject()` for the **last one only**... but **before** `EndPaint()` (while the font is being select to the DC).

I've found this example so misleading about the way `DeleteObject()` must be used. 
I hope if someone could confirm or justify this code.

The example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
    {


    case WM_PAINT:
        {
        RECT rect;
        HBRUSH hBrush;
        HFONT hFont;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);


            //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 48 pixels in height.
            //The width, when set to 0, will cause the font mapper to choose the closest matching value.
            //The font face name will be Impact.
            hFont = CreateFont(48,0,0,0,FW_DONTCARE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
                CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("Impact"));
            SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

            //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
            SetRect(&rect, 100,100,700,200);
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0));
            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Impact"), -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);


            //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 36 pixels in height.
            //The width, when set to 20, will cause the font mapper to choose a font which, in this case, is stretched.
            //The font face name will be Times New Roman.  This time nEscapement is at -300 tenths of a degree (-30 degrees)
            hFont = CreateFont(36,20,-300,0,FW_DONTCARE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
                CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("Times New Roman"));
            SelectObject(hdc,hFont);

            //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
            SetRect(&rect, 100, 200, 900, 800);
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,128,0));
            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Times New Roman"), -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);


            //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 36 pixels in height.
            //The width, when set to 10, will cause the font mapper to choose a font which, in this case, is compressed. 
            //The font face name will be Arial. This time nEscapement is at 250 tenths of a degree (25 degrees)
            hFont = CreateFont(36,10,250,0,FW_DONTCARE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
                CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("Arial"));
            SelectObject(hdc,hFont);

            //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
            SetRect(&rect, 500, 200, 1400, 600);
            SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Arial"), -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);
            DeleteObject(hFont);    

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  You know how to fix it.

Comment: @hans, no I don't.

Comment: There's an [edit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta.md) link at the top right corner of the documentation page. Click it and fix the sample implementation.

Comment: Oh didn't see that, thanks.

Comment: I made an [update](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/commit/1c11f9ac6815bc58ec93acf4e5d98e02330633ea).

Comment: @perrahmaouy the original `HFONT` returned by the 1st `SelectObject()` call needs to be saved so it can be restored before calling `EndPaint()`.