# CreateFont, DeleteObject and GDI handle/memory leak

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am looking at this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta of `CreateFont` API

It clearly says that after the font been created with `CreateFont` it should be destroyed by `DeleteObject` call. `DeleteObject(hFont);`  is only called once. `CreateFont` is called 3 times. Is this a bug in the MS docs? Shouldn't the old font be stored by retrieving it with `SelectObject` and set back after new fonts been used?

Comment: As a general comment, do not trust the code snippets in MS documentation pages to be more than just that - code snippets. They are certainly not real, or even "sample" code - and you would probably not want production level code in a doc page, anyway. For actual samples, see their [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples) and links therein, instead.

Comment: Someone else [asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61228227/1889329) earlier this year. They attempted to fix the documentation, but only made it worse. Thankfully, the pull request never was merged into the official documentation.

Comment: Looks pretty bad. I just read through comments threads on that pull request...

Comment: Hi,if any answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two of the created font objects are leaked.

Note that MS sample code is generally poor about error handling and object cleanup (they generally focus on demonstrating whatever is central to the sample - here the CreateFont call - while ignoring or minimizing those issues).

Comment: Actually, all three are leaked, because the original font is not restored in the device context, and quoting Raymond Chen's [What are the dire consequences of not selecting objects out of my DC?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130306-00/?p=5043): "*if you select a font into a DC, and somebody tries to destroy the font, the Delete­Object call will fail, and you end up leaking a font*".

Comment: @dxiv Interesting article, thank you. This was relevant on Win9X Oses, when not selecting back the GDI object consumed all system GDI resources, particularly handles. On NT based systems the problem of leaking handles does not seem to be there. The "leaking" memory (I am talking about the GDI object that was not restored back by SelectObject) would just sit there until the process is terminated.

Comment: @dgrandm No, the only difference is that in NT-based systems the handles are closed when the process exits. But there still is a system-wide limit on GDI handles ([64K](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects)) so if yours is a long-running process any such cumulative leak will eventually bite you.

Comment: @dxiv so it is safe to assume on NT systems if I do not restore back the original GDI handle that was assigned to DC it will not be leaked system-wide since it will be closed by the process? I vaguely remember that on 9X it was a system-wide leak after the process was closed.

Comment: @dgrandm Yes, that is [safe to assume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process) since early NT.

Answer (score 1):

The example in the documentation did cause the leak of the font object

I built a sample as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
    {


    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rect;
        HBRUSH hBrush;
        HFONT hFont;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);


        //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 48 pixels in height.
        //The width, when set to 0, will cause the font mapper to choose the closest matching value.
        //The font face name will be Impact.
        hFont = CreateFont(48, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT("Impact"));
        SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

        //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
        SetRect(&rect, 100, 100, 700, 200);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Impact"), -1, &rect, DT_NOCLIP);

        //DeleteObject(hFont);
        //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 36 pixels in height.
        //The width, when set to 20, will cause the font mapper to choose a font which, in this case, is stretched.
        //The font face name will be Times New Roman.  This time nEscapement is at -300 tenths of a degree (-30 degrees)
        hFont = CreateFont(36, 20, -300, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT("Times New Roman"));
        SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

        //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
        SetRect(&rect, 100, 200, 900, 800);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 128, 0));
        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Times New Roman"), -1, &rect, DT_NOCLIP);

        //DeleteObject(hFont);
        //Logical units are device dependent pixels, so this will create a handle to a logical font that is 36 pixels in height.
        //The width, when set to 10, will cause the font mapper to choose a font which, in this case, is compressed. 
        //The font face name will be Arial. This time nEscapement is at 250 tenths of a degree (25 degrees)
        hFont = CreateFont(36, 10, 250, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT("Arial"));
        SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

        //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
        SetRect(&rect, 500, 200, 1400, 600);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Drawing Text with Arial"), -1, &rect, DT_NOCLIP);
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Start the task manager after running the sample, you can see it in details:

[image]
[image]

Then trigger a WM_PAINT message:

[image]

We can find that its GDI Objects has increased by 2, and it will increase every time it is triggered, so this example will cause object leakage.

When we call `DeleteObject(hFont);` after each use(In line 75 and line 88 of my sample), and repeat the above steps, we will find that GDI Objects will not increase, thus solving the problem of object leakage.